# UpdatePanel with multiple DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

**EDIT: It was `DropDownList.Items.Clear();` in a method where I listed some stuff from db, that caused the problem. however, I do not understand why this would cause the problem. I would really appreciate if I could give an explanation, since I really need to use Items.Clear(); somehow**

I got 3 `DropDownList`, where I update a specific label depending on which value I select within one of these 3 `DropDownList`. Every `DropDownList` works fine, until I pick the next one, and the others before it will not trigger via UpdatePanel.

E.g. First one works, but stops working(the label wont update) once I use the second one.
The second works but once third `DropDownList` is used, the second wont work either, and only the third `DropDownList` is working fine.

Same goes if I, immediately use the third, the first and second `DropDownList` wont work via UpdatePanel.

In other word, once the latest `DropDownList` is being used, every `DropDownList` before it wont trigger via UpdatePanel.

**aspx:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dpl1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dpl1_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="dpl2" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dpl2_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="dpl3" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dpl3_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
  <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="lblDPB" runat="server"/>
  </ContentTemplate>

  <Triggers>
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dpl1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dpl2" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dpl3" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code behind:**

```
 protected void dpl1_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        lblDPB.Text = "#1: ";
    }

    protected void dpl2_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        lblDPB.Text = "#2: ";
    }

    protected void dpl3_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblDPB.Text = "#3: ";          
    }
```

**How can I make all these 3 works simultaneously?**

Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. I see the correct list number when I select from any of them, in any order. I fill the lists in `Page_Load` (I don't know how yours are filled). Is this a small part of a more complicated form? If so, you could test that part in a small test project. By the way, does the problem occur if you wait 5 seconds between your actions?

Comment: @ConnorsFan hmm strange.. It also worked for me when I simply listed some stuff in Page_Load. In my code I added some values from db to dropdownlist via a method, used, this.PreRender += MethodName in Page_Load. It's too much code to add here, but what could possible bug my code? I simply connected to db(using OleDb), added stuff into each DropDownList and closed the connection in that "MethodName". Btw, I waited over 5 sec, still same problem.

Comment: EDIT: Okay I found the problem, in the beginning of "MethodName", I got Items.Clear for each DropDownList, why is that causing that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing and populating the DropDownList on each postback messes up the selection in the list. Calling `Items.Clear()` empties the `SelectedValue` and sets the `SelectedIndex` to -1. After filling the list, the first item is selected. All that processing causes the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to fire at unexpected moments.

One way to avoid this problem is to save the selected values before calling `Items.Clear()`, and to set them back after refilling the lists:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...

    string val1 = dpl1.SelectedValue;
    string val2 = dpl2.SelectedValue;
    string val3 = dpl3.SelectedValue;

    dpl1.Items.Clear();
    dpl2.Items.Clear();
    dpl3.Items.Clear();

    // Fill the lists here

    SafeSelectValue(dpl1, val1);
    SafeSelectValue(dpl2, val2);
    SafeSelectValue(dpl3, val3);
}

private void SafeSelectValue(ListControl lst, string value)
{
    // Makes sure that the value exists before selecting it
    if (lst.Items.FindByValue(value) != null)
    {
        lst.SelectedValue = value;
    }
}
```

By the way, in order to see the changes in the lists items, I needed to put the three DropDownLists inside an UpdatePanel with `UpdateMode="Always"`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="dpl1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dpl1_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="dpl2" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dpl2_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="dpl3" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dpl3_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Just a thing, I forgot to mention about that my DropDownList contents changes depend on search to db. I'm getting error when I try to change the content in dpl " 'dpl1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value". The solution works fine if the content dosnt change, but I've no idea how to handle it if it does. I couldn't find any proper solution.

Comment: This topic has a few twists and turns that make it interesting. I updated my answer.